# How do I make a specular surface without reflections?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have tried to make it with a Glossy shader node. But I either get glossy with reflections or matte surface with small reflective details.

Answer (score 2):

Gloss is essentially the same thing as specularity.  Glossy means that rays reflect off the surface at the angle of incidence (specular angle), producing a reflection.

From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloss_(optics)):

> Gloss is an optical property of a surface to reflect light in a specular (mirror-like) direction.

*By definition*, gloss (or specularity) will give you reflections, and thus “gloss without reflections” is a self contradicting statement.  So, short of some compositing tricks as sambler has explained in his answer, it isn't really possible to have gloss without reflections.

The *roughness* slider simulates miniscule roughness in the surface by scattering rays slightly away from the angle of incidence, giving the matte-like shading.

Answer (score 1):

A glossy shader will show reflections of objects and lights around it. To remove the reflections you want to separate the object by using [render layers](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Post_Process/Layers) and then composite it together.

The trick to what you want to achieve is to have the object on a scene layer by itself, then setup a render layer to show that one scene layer and exclude other scene layers.

Here layer 2 is enabled and layer 1 is excluded

[image]

Giving you this ball by itself

[image]

but the other layer still sees it so has reflections of the ball in between.

[image]

composited together you get a ball in the middle without reflections

[image]